# Retrieving data from Firebase DB taking far too long (20 seconds)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am querying two tables from Firebase DB, when querying `cars` table I get a response from firebase instantaneously (about a second) but when querying `users` table it takes about 20 seconds to get a response.
Both users and cars table have about 6 records each and both have similar database rules (please see below).
Please also find the data structure in both tables.
Can someone please advice where I could be going wrong ?

Code for querying `users` table:

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users'); 
usersRef.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
  $scope.usersList = [];
  var usersObject    =   dataSnapshot.val();
    for(key in usersObject){
      var userObject = usersObject[key];
      $scope.usersList.push(userObject);
    }
})
```

Code for querying `cars` table:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('cars');
ref.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) { 
  var carObjects   =   dataSnapshot.val();
  $scope.carsList = [];
  for(key in carObjects){
    var carObject = carObjects[key];
      $scope.carsList.push(carObject);
  }
})
```

Database Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read":  "auth != null ",
      ".write": "auth != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('userType').val() === 'Admin'"
    },
    "cars": {
      ".read":  "auth != null ",
      ".write": "auth != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('userType').val() === 'Admin'"
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the data structure for Users

[image: Users Data Structure]

Below is the data structure for Cars

[image: Cars Data Structure]

Comment: are all the values in "users" just short text?

Comment: With the current info in your question the only thing i can think of that is affecting the downloadspeed is the size of the users and cars you are getting. What are the values inside car and user? How big are they?

Comment: Most often the time it takes to synchronize data is a function of the amount of data and the available bandwidth. In other words: the only way to improve it is to download less data or wait for a better connection. You could of course be hitting a more unique scenario, but it's impossible to say with the current information. Can you set up a [**minimal** reproduction of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in jsbin?

Comment: All the values inside car and user are 'strings' less then 50 characters each in length.

Comment: There's nothing we can do without reproducing the issue. Unless you set up a jsbin that reproduces it, the best we can do is see how long it takes for us to load the data. For that: replace the picture-of-JSON with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.